# How to change another users session with php

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

I am going to explain this with an example
Jake and Kevin own a company called facebook, they want a means of advertisement so they create an account named facebook and immediately after creating it **both** of them login to the account and start advertising, later Jake wanted to change the name of their company to stackoverflow so he went to the settings and did just that, problem now is that on jakes laptop the name is stackoverflow but on kevin's laptop the name is facebook
How can i make it that at the point of submission my php script checks if the user name for anyother session is facebook and change it to stackoverflow

Comment: When someone changes the name, it should update a "company" record in the database, which both users are connected to. In the sessions, just store the session id and load the user and the connected company data from the database on each page load. That way, they will always have the latest info on every page load.

Comment: You can use pusher https://pusher.com/ to notify to client when update db